# Emit to a specific client with Sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to make a little party system just for practice with sockets, I've come into a snag, basically my methodology for this party system will just be

On page load, ask for username, populate all clients with new username which is an anchor with the id of their username, when anchor is clicked, send the specific client a request to invite them to a party.

I've almost gotten to the part with sending the link, so far I have:

```
socket.on('adduser', function(username) {
  socket.username = username;
  socket.clientId = socket.id;
  usernames[username] = username;
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', 'You have connected.');
  io.sockets.emit('updateusers', usernames);
  console.log(usernames);
});
```

for creating new users
and

```
socket.on('updateusers', function(data) {
  var users = document.getElementById('users');
  users.innerHTML = '';
  for (var key in data) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.id = key;
        a.href='#';
        a.innerHTML = key;
    users.appendChild(a);
    users.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
    document.getElementById(key).addEventListener('click', function() { 
      inviteUser.call(this); 
    });
  }
});
```

for the client side

I'm just getting confused on how to send the emit to a specific user instead of to everybody,

normally I would `socket.emit` to send an emit to the user that requested the whatever, but now I need to send to somebody else

I was thinking of storing a socket.id into an object and sending the request to the id that matches the username, but how can I emit to a specific ID?

**TL;DR**: How can I send an emit to a specific `socket.id` so only they get the request.

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Store all sockets in an array. When a user connects and you get the `socket` object, store `listOfSockets[socket.id] = socket;`, where `listOfSockets` is declared in the global (or at least the next-level-up) scope.

Comment: @apsillers That's the method I was getting at, but how do I emit to the specific ID?

Comment: Since the list is indexed by ID, you can do `listOfSockets[someId].emit(...)`

Comment: Oh so you can emit directly to a socket.id? In a verbose way it would look like `SsJX4Xdzy88-6dg2GRFW.emit(...);`?

Comment: No, a socket ID is a string, not a socket. Let me explain it more clearly: `listOfSockets` is an object (which we'll think of an associative array for now). We store sockets inside of `listOfSockets`. When you ask for the value of `listOfSockets[someId]`, you get a socket object. That socket object lives at the index `someId` in `listOfSockets`. The socket object you get back has an `emit` function. (The `someId` string you *used* to *get* that socket object does not have an `emit` function -- you're calling `listOfSockets[someId].emit`, *not* `someId.emit`.)

Answer (score -1):

Well you have to grab the client for that , you can either go the simple way:

```
var io = io.listen(server);

io.clients[sessionID].send();
```

Which may break, I hardly doubt it, but it's always a possibility that io.clients might get changed, so use the above with caution

Or you keep track of the clients yourself, therefore you add them to your own clients object in the connection listener and remove them in the disconnect listener.